# Regex for 8-digit expression without hyphen or letters

Tags: regex

Currently, I have this:

```
Regex folderRegex = new Regex(@"^.{8})([0-9]+)?[1-9]+([0-9]+)?$");
```

I need the string to have exactly 8 digits. Without hyphens or letters. Would my regex do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need a very simple pattern.

```
^\d{8}$
```

Short description

- Assert position at the beginning of the string `^`
- Match a single digit 0..9 `\d`

  - Exactly 8 times `{8}`
- Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any) `$`

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the same thing using a character class with a grouping range.

```
Regex folderRegex = new Regex(@"^[0-9]{8}$");
```

Regular expression:

```
[0-9]{8}    any character of: '0' to '9' (8 times)
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming from what is given in your question that you do not want your string of eight digits to start with a `0`, this should do:

```
^[1-9]\d{7}$
```